# Jump to top of function definition in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

If the last executed command is a long function definition, I have to press the up key many times to get to a previous command. How can I jump to the top of the function from the bottom line or skip over the function definition entirely to get to a previous command?

```
[1]: # want to get here

[2]: def f():
         x = 'foo'
         # many lines
         return x

[3]: f() # currently here
```

Comment: Try ctrl upArrow

Comment: or try PageUp..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, `Ctrl + UpArrow` or `PageUp` give you the desired scrolling by each executed statement rather than line-by-line that a simple `UpArrow` provides.